# aws apns push notification 500 error

Tags: java, ios, amazon-web-services, notifications

I am new to amazon push notifications android notification work fine but the problem arises when it comes to apple push notifications. I have created new certificate for production environment exported the private key and converted both the certificate and private key to pem format. When i try to send notification using java code i am getting 500 error and when i try to send using amazon console the notification is published and the device receives it.The following error is what i get when i try to send notification using java program.

```
===========================================

Getting Started with Amazon SNS
===========================================

Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to     Amazon SNS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    Request could not be completed (Service: AmazonSNS;     Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalError; Request ID:     238e7020-5f23-5d76-89aa-3f6707fde345)
HTTP Status Code: 500
AWS Error Code:   InternalError
Error Type:       Service
Request ID:       238e7020-5f23-5d76-89aa-3f6707fde345
```

Comment: 500 is an internal Server error. You should look in the Server logfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be because of the certificate and private key you are using. If you are able to send notification using the amazon console then try to take the private key and certificate that is generated in the console when you enter the private key.p12 and the password while creating the platform application and open the pem files replace content in the certificate and private key in pem files with the ones with amazon certificate and private key and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

- 1) Check your security key in properties file

  - static String ACCESS_KEY = "";
  - static String SECRET_KEY = "";
- 2) Check Certificate
  key and  \n is there in start and end of STring

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html#verify-cert-private-key-apns
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/using-awssdkjava.html

If you could share logs so may be give you actual rootcause